# Issues adding attribute to XML root node via augeas

Tags: xml, puppet, augeas

I am using augeas to manipulate XML on some machines. Whereas creating new nodes and also setting a bunch of attributes worked like a charm I'm biting my nails of adding a simple attribute to an XML file. XML looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Context>
   <WatchedResource></WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

I'm no just trying to add `allowLinking="true"` to the Context root node via

```
set /files/path/to/my/file.xml/Context/#attribute/allowLinking "true"
```

Which is unfortunately always failing with

```
/error = "put_failed"
/error/path = "/files/path/to/my/file.xml/Context"
/error/lens = "/usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/xml.aug:134.10-.73:"
/error/message = "Failed to match \n    { /#attribute/ }?({ /#text/ …
```

I'm using puppet opensource 3.4.2 with augeas 1.0.0.

Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order matters in the Augeas tree. In that case, XML node attributes need to be set before the `#text` node and the child nodes.

So what you need is:

```
ins #attribute before /files/test.xml/Context/#text
set /files/test.xml/Context/#attribute/allowLinking true
```

Note that this change is not idempotent, since `insert` is not an idempotent operation.

On Puppet, you could use `onlyif` to make this idempotent.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. Now I only have to take care of the cases where there is no #text node or an already existent #attribute. ;-)

Comment: Indeed. For complex cases, you might want to write a type and an Augeas-based provider using AugeasProviders (see augeasproviders.com).