# Using augeas with puppet to add an attribute to a root node

Tags: xml, puppet, augeas

So I'm trying to do something that looks identical to the question at "[Issues adding attribute to XML root node via augeas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289801/issues-adding-attribute-to-xml-root-node-via-augeas)", but the answer provided there doesn't work for me.  Without the insert command, I'm getting this error message (in `puppet agent -t --debug --verbose` mode):

```
Debug: Augeas[context.xml](provider=augeas): /augeas/files/usr/share/tomcat/conf/context.xml/error/message = Failed to match 
    { /#attribute/ }?({ /#text/ = /(\\]\\]\\]*[^]\001-\004<>][^]\001-\004<]*\\]|(\\][^]\001-\004<]|[^]\001-\004<][^]\001-\004<])[^]\001-\004<]*\\]|[^]\001-\004<]\\])(\\]\\]*[^]\001-\004<>][^]\001-\004<]*\\]|[^]\001-\004<][^]\001-\004<]*\\])*(\\]\\]*([^]\001-\004<>][^]\001-\004<]*|)|[^]\001-\004<][^]\001-\004<]*|)|\\]\\]\\]*([^]\001-\004<>][^]\001-\004<]*|)|(\\][^]\001-\004<]|[^]\001-\004<][^]\001-\004<])[^]\001-\004<]*|\\]|[^]\001-\004<]/ } | { /#comment/ = /([^\001-\004-]|-[^\001-\004-])*/ } | <<rec>> | { /[:A-Z_a-z][.0-:A-Z_a-z-]*/ = /#empty/ } | { /#pi/ })*
  with tree
    { "#text" = "

    " } { "#comment" = " Default set of monitored resources " } { "#text" = "
    " } { "WatchedResource" } { "#text" = "
    " } { "#comment" = " Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts " } { "#text" = "
    " } { "#comment" = "
    <Manager pathname="" />
    " } { "#text" = "

    " } { "#comment" = " Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) " } { "#text" = "
    " } { "#comment" = "
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    " } { "#text" = "

" } { "Manager" } { "#attribute" }
Debug: Augeas[context.xml](provider=augeas): Closed the augeas connection
Error: /Stage[main]/mytomcat::Hardening::Context-xml/Augeas[context.xml]: Could not evaluate: Saving failed, see debug
```

Which is basically what we saw in that other post.  With the insert command, here's the relevant code I'm using:

```
class mytomcat::hardening::context-xml {
  require ::augeas
  augeas{ 'context.xml':
    lens    => 'Xml.lns',
    incl    => '/usr/share/tomcat/conf/context.xml',
    changes => [
      'ins #attribute before Context/#text',
      'set Context/#attribute/allowLinking false', 
    ],
  }
}
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Debug: Augeas[context.xml](provider=augeas): sending command 'ins' with params ["#attribute", "before", "/files/usr/share/tomcat/conf/context.xml/Context/#text"]
Debug: Augeas[context.xml](provider=augeas): Closed the augeas connection
Error: /Stage[main]/mytomcat::Hardening::Context-xml/Augeas[context.xml]: Could not evaluate: Error sending command 'ins' with params ["#attribute", "before", "/files/usr/share/tomcat/conf/context.xml/Context/#text"]/Error sending command 'ins' with params ["#attribute", "before", "/files/usr/share/tomcat/conf/context.xml/Context/#text"]
```

I tried using `touch` instead of `insert`, based on the "[Puppet Type Reference](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#augeas)" page for Augeas with this code:

```
class mytomcat::hardening::context-xml {
  require ::augeas
  augeas{ 'context.xml':
    lens    => 'Xml.lns',
    incl    => '/usr/share/tomcat/conf/context.xml',
    changes => [
      'touch Context/#attribute',
      'touch Context/#attribute/allowLinking',
      'set Context/#attribute/allowLinking false', 
    ],
  }
}
```

But then I get the error message:

```
Error: /Stage[main]/mytomcat::Hardening::Context-xml/Augeas[context.xml]: Could not evaluate: Unknown command touch
```

EDIT: I tried doing a `clear` instead of touch, but that seems to be a NOOP command, and does not give me a different result than the first one shown at the very top of this post.

So, I can't do `touch`, using a full XPath to try to set the attribute doesn't work because you have to add the #attribute node before the #text node, `clear` appears to be a NOOP, and then when I try to do the "insert" command as recommended it also doesn't work.

Any idea what is going wrong here and how I can fix it?

Comment: When running with `--debug --verbose`, is there any helpful output at all?

Comment: I updated my post above to show the debugging information, but I don't think it's helpful.

Comment: What version of Puppet are you using? It looks like the touch command was added in Puppet 4.0: https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1413

Comment: it seems to be related to the path, you could try changing `touch` => `/usr/bin/touch`