# how to update existing or create new XML node with Augeas

Tags: xml, puppet, augeas

For the following XML:

```
<properties>
  <entry key="foo">bar</entry>
</properties>
```

I can update exiting entry with attribute "foo" with the following augeas command:

```
set /files/test.xml/properties/entry[#attribute/key='foo']/#text bar2
```

Is there augeas command(s) to create a new node (with key attribute) if there is no existing entry with the input attribute, and update existing if entry already exists with the input attribute?  I tried the following:

```
set /files/test.xml/properties/entry[#attribute/key='hello']/#text world
```

But this only results in the following, without attribute:

```
<properties>
  <entry key="foo">bar2</entry>
  <entry>world</entry>
</properties>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues adding attribute to XML root node via augeas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289801/issues-adding-attribute-to-xml-root-node-via-augeas)

Answer (score 2):

`/files/test.xml/properties/entry[#attribute/key='hello']/#text` doesn't match any node, so Augeas creates a new node. If you want to update both values.

Apparently, you want to keep only one `entry` node and set both its text and `key` attribute:

```
defnode entry /files/test.xml/properties/entry[#attribute/key="foo"]
set $entry/#attribute/key 'hello'
set $entry/#text 'world'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this output:

```
<properties>
    <entry key="foo">bar</entry>
    <entry key="hello">world</entry>
</properties>
```

The following code should do the trick:

```
set /augeas/load/Xml/incl[2] /path/to/file.xml
load
defvar properties "/files/path/to/file.xml/properties"
set $properties/entry[last()+1]/#attribute/key "hello"
set $properties/entry[last()]/#text "world"
save
```

Comment: This works but is not idempotent. Every run of this script will create a new entry with key "hello" and text "world".