# Adding new nodes to XML file with Augeas

Tags: xml, augeas

I have this XML file **/opt/webapp/config.xml** for a custom webapp that contains a parent node **items**.

```
<items>
</items>
```

I'm trying to add a list of new child nodes **item** with an attribute **value** while making sure the child node doesn't contain the end/closing tag because the app requires that format.

```
<items>
<item value="video/*"/><item value="audio/*"/><item value="application/rar"/><item value="application/x-zip"/><item value="application/x-gzip"/>
</items>
```

If I were to open up the existing configuration using augtool, I will get the below output.

```
/files/opt/webapp/config.xml/File/FileTypes
/files/opt/webapp/config.xml/File/FileTypes/#text = "\n"
/files/opt/webapp/config.xml/File/FileTypes/items
/files/opt/webapp/config.xml/File/FileTypes/items/#text = "\n"
/files/opt/webapp/config.xml/File/FileTypes/items/item[1] = "#empty"
/files/opt/webapp/config.xml/File/FileTypes/items/item[1]/#attribute
/files/opt/webapp/config.xml/File/FileTypes/items/item[1]/#attribute/value = "video/*"
/files/opt/webapp/config.xml/File/FileTypes/items/item[2] = "#empty"
/files/opt/webapp/config.xml/File/FileTypes/items/item[2]/#attribute
/files/opt/webapp/config.xml/File/FileTypes/items/item[2]/#attribute/value = "audio/*"
/files/opt/webapp/config.xml/File/FileTypes/items/item[3] = "#empty"
/files/opt/webapp/config.xml/File/FileTypes/items/item[3]/#attribute
/files/opt/webapp/config.xml/File/FileTypes/items/item[3]/#attribute/value = "application/rar"
```

I found a few posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289801/issues-adding-attribute-to-xml-root-node-via-augeas) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083343/how-to-update-existing-or-create-new-xml-node-with-augeas) discussing about xml and Augeas but those examples follow the format with both starting and closing tag. For example: `<item value="application/rar"></item>`. And I'm trying to find a way to see if Augeas can also create and add child node with a self-closing tag only.

I'm using augtool (version 1.10.1) that comes with puppet agent 5.5.10 on RHEL 7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your example, self-closing tags have a value of `#empty`, so you just need to set that value on your items.

So in your case, you could do something like:

```
# set context to use relative paths later
set /augeas/context /files/opt/webapp/config.xml/File/FileTypes/items

# define a $video variable pointing to the video element, define it as self-closing
defnode video item[#attribute/value="video/*"] "#empty"
# Set element value
set $video/#attribute/value "video/*"

defnode audio item[#attribute/value="audio/*"] "#empty"
set $audio/#attribute/value "audio/*"

defnode rar item[#attribute/value="application/rar"] "#empty"
set $rar/#attribute/value "application/rar"
```

etc.

resulting in:

```xml
<items>
<item value="video/*"/>
<item value="audio/*"/>
<item value="application/rar"/>
</items>
```

`defnode` will define a variable that points to a node and set its value if it doesn't exist yet. As a result, this code will be idempotent.

Comment: Thank you. This works out exactly as I intended. Also just found out that Augeas would take care of adding and modifying the configs but won't handle the indentation and formatting. Guess that will have to be done separately.

Comment: Yes, Augeas willingly ignores formatting. You'll need to use a formatter/beautifier for that if you care about it.